# Collection<string> cannot accept string values

Tags: c#, collections

I have Silverlight application.I have page Home.xaml(and its code-behind Home.xaml.cs).There is the button. when I click on the button, the OpenFileDialog opens, i change from my computer *.txt file . convert it to data stream.then call completely another class Processr.cs, where this data stream will proccess and result will add to Coolection. Problem , that my result val cannot add to collection. the following code is executed:

**Home.xaml.cs:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    opendialog.Multiselect = true;
    bool? dialogResult = opendialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
    {
        Stream fileStream = opendialog.File.OpenRead();
        var processor = new Processor();
        ICollection<string> results = processor.Process(fileStream);
    }
}
```

**Processor.cs**

```
 public class Processor
 {
 public ICollection<string> Process(Stream stream)
 {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var matches =
            Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .Distinct();

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
            return new Collection<string>().Add(val);;  //here error

        }

    }

}
```

**such error:**

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'

Comment: Because `Collection.Add` method's _return type_ is `void`. It doesn't return anything. But you are saying; `Process` method returns `ICollection<string>` in your method definition. Reconsider to your architecture..

Comment: it is clear to you, but I do not.:) Tell me how to fix it!

Comment: Either change your `Process` method _return type_ to `void` or, return `ICollection<string>` in your method  without any changing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning  a method instead of an  `Instance object` this why you  are getting this exception message.  In  addition you are doing wrongly  your processing

here a fix

```
public class Processor
 {
 public ICollection<string> Process(Stream stream)
 {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
    Collection<string> myCollection = new Collection<string>(); 
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var matches =
            Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .Distinct();

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
      myCollection.Add(val);;  //here error

        }

    }
return myCollection;  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Add` method of `Collection<>` does not return the collection itself. It is not chainable.

Also, your implementation would `return` after adding **the first item**, and not all items, which I assume that you want.

Try this:

```
    var result = new Collection<string>();

    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
        result.Add(val);
    }

}
return result;
```

Besides, there are lots of weird stuff going on in your code. First, you are calling `ReadToEnd` inside a `while` loop, which doesn't really make sense. Second, you are not calling `Dispose` on your `StreamReader` *(or using the `using` keyword)*.

Does the file consist of commands, separated by newlines? If the file is potentially really big, I would go for a custom iterator, using the `yield` keyword. That way, the entire contents of the file would not have to be in memory at once, but rather just one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

[`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not return anything(`void`), that's why you get the exception. You have to return something that implements `ICollection<string>`. You could use `ToList`:

```
return matches.Select(m => m + Environment.NewLine).ToList();
```

You are also returning a collection with one item in a loop which is pointless.

Side-note: since you're adding  `Environment.NewLine` i guess that you actually want a single string where each match is separated by a new-line. Then you could use `String.Join` (change return type):

```
return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, matches);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sorry about that. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Really were meaningless strings in my code. Thank you pointed this out!Correct in my answer/

Answer (score 0):

The Add method does not return a value. To resolve this, the best option is to replace the line

```
return new Collection<object>().Add(val);
```

with

```
return new Collection<object>() { val };
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead of Process method:

```
    public ICollection<object> Process(Stream stream)
    {
        Collection<object> collection = new Collection<object>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var matches =
                Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                    .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .Distinct();

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
                collection.Add(val);
            }
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed from the code meaningless loop *`While`* and such string-code:

```
var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
```

**Processor.cs:**

```
public class Processor
    {

        public IList<string> Process(Stream
             stream)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
            List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

                var matches =
                    Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                        .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                        .Distinct();


                    foreach (var match in matches)
                    {
                    myCollection.Add(match);
                    }


            return myCollection;


        }
    }
```